# Preventing an output of a function from being assigned a value

Tags: functions, function-construction, attributes

Say I have a function

`Example[n_Integer]:=n{x,y,z}`

`Example@4`

> {4 x, 4 y, 4 z}

Now, let us assign some values to `x,y,z`

`x=7
 y=7
 z=8`

And then we evaluate our function again

`Example@4`

> {28, 28, 32}

How can I make it so that despite some values being assigned to the variables `x,y,z` the output of the function `Example` is only affected by its argument `n`? I have tried to use `SetAttributes[Example,Protected]` but that does not work. Could someone help?

Comment: Can you provide more details of why you want to do this? I think you oversimplified your actual issue.

Comment: @CarlWoll I produce a list of symbolic expression, for instance `{-x,-y,x,y,x+y,y+z.}`

Comment: So, something like: `Example[n_Integer]:=(Clear[x,y,z]; n{x,y,z})` will work for you?

Comment: @CarlWoll I produce a list of symbolic expressions, for instance `l = {-x,-y,x,y,x+y,y+z}`. I then write a function that assigns some expression to `x` and `y`, for example `x={1,-1,0},y={0,1,-1}` so then automatically the remaining symbols in `l` get assigned a value. Then  I want to find a reflection of  one of the expression in `l` in the hyperplane perpendicular to, say `x`. Once I do that, I'd get, for example, `{-1,1,0}`. Now, I want to know to which symbol in my initial `l` that value corresponds, if that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry @CarlWoll I didn't mean to post that first comment, but then I was editing it for too long. Explaining further, my idea was to get the position of the reflection output in the "updated" `l` and then extract a symbolic expression from a list which was the same as my initial `l`, so say, from `Identifier ={-x,-y,x,y,x+y,y+z}`.

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you maybe update your question to reflect what you are truly after?

Comment: @Roman I've posted more detailed question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199298/tracking-back-a-variable-corresponding-to-an-output

Answer (score 2):

Just avoid setting x and y.

For example:

```
f2[l_, n_] := n l;

Clear[x, y, z]
masterl = {x, y, z};
```

Then you can substitute in values if you want:

```
xx = 3; yy = 4;
l2 = masterl /. {x -> xx, y -> yy}

(* {3, 4, z} *)
```

Or do some work with the original list:

```
f2[masterl, 5]

(* {5 x, 5 y, 5 z} *)
```