# Tracking back a variable corresponding to an output

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

I have a function:

```
An[n_Integer]:=  
 Join[-Table[Subscript[\[Alpha], i],{i,1,n}],Table[Subscript[\[Alpha], i],{i,1,n}],
  Plus@@@Flatten[Table[Partition[#,i,1],{i,2,n}]& @ Table[Subscript[\[Alpha], i],{i,1,n}],1]
  ]
```

Which gives me a list, for example:

`An[2]`

> {-Subscript[[Alpha], 1], -Subscript[[Alpha], 
>     2], Subscript[[Alpha], 1], Subscript[[Alpha], 2], 
>    Subscript[[Alpha], 1] + Subscript[[Alpha], 2]}

Now I assign:

`SR = Table[Subscript[\[Alpha], i]=ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0,n+1],{i->1,i+1->-1}],{i,1,n}]`

So now if `An` is executed all the elements in the output list are determined by `SN`, for instance:

`An[2][[1]]`

> {-1, 1, 0}

Now, I have a function that finds a reflection of a vector, in a mirror through the origin, normal to some vector:

`Reflection[l_List,k_List]:=Module[{rt=ReflectionTransform[l]},
  rt[k]
    ]`

So for instance:

`Reflection[Subscript[\[Alpha], 1],Subscript[\[Alpha], 1]]`

> {-1, 1, 0}

We can see that the list above corresponds to `An[2][[1]]`
 which was `-Subscript[[Alpha], 1]` before the `SR` was defined. This is my question, how can I define this 'tracking back' computationally? So, basically, the output of the `Reflection` function should be one of the

`{-Subscript[[Alpha], 1], -Subscript[[Alpha], 2], Subscript[[Alpha], 1], Subscript[[Alpha], 2], Subscript[[Alpha], 1] + Subscript[[Alpha], 2]}`

or an empty list, if the vector after reflection doesn't match with any of the `An`, where `An` is executed after defining `SR`. I fell like I am somehow over complicating this, but don't seem to be able to figure this out. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best would be to never make any assignments to the $\alpha_i$ and keep the replacement rules in `SR` as a list of rules. Also, the decomposition at the end can be done with a `PseudoInverse`. Here's a working version:

```
An[n_Integer] := 
  Join[-Table[Subscript[α, i], {i, 1, n}], 
        Table[Subscript[α, i], {i, 1, n}], 
        Plus @@@ Flatten[Table[Partition[#, i, 1], {i, 2, n}] &@
          Table[Subscript[α, i], {i, 1, n}], 1]]

An[2]
```

> $$
> \left\{-\alpha _1,-\alpha _2,\alpha _1,\alpha _2,\alpha _1+\alpha _2\right\}
> $$

Construct `SR` as a list of rules instead of assigning to the $\alpha_i$:

```
With[{n = 2},
  SR = Table[Subscript[α, i] -> 
    ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, n + 1], {i -> 1, i + 1 -> -1}], {i, 1, n}]]
```

> $$
> \left\{\alpha _1\to \{1,-1,0\},\alpha _2\to \{0,1,-1\}\right\}
> $$

Extract the information from these rules:

```
F = PseudoInverse[SR[[All, 2]]];
f = SR[[All, 1]];
```

Try out the rules:

```
An[2] /. SR
```

> $$
> \{\{-1, 1, 0\}, \{0, -1, 1\}, \{1, -1, 0\}, \{0, 1, -1\}, \{1, 0, -1\}\}
> $$

```
Reflection[l_List, k_List] := Module[{rt = ReflectionTransform[l]}, rt[k]]
```

Try out a reflection:

```
Reflection[Subscript[α, 1] /. SR, Subscript[α, 1] /. SR]
```

> $$
>  \{-1, 1, 0\}
> $$

Convert into an expression with $\alpha_i$:

```
(%.F).f
```

> $$
>  -\alpha_1
> $$

Do this with all elements of `An[2]`:

```
((An[2] /. SR).F).f
```

> $$
> \left\{-\alpha _1,-\alpha _2,\alpha _1,\alpha _2,\alpha _1+\alpha _2\right\}
> $$

Comment: That is great, thank you so much! I have never heard of pseudoinverses before, I really like your idea!